# Rest argument , zero or one argument procedures in racket

Tags: rest, lisp, arguments, scheme, racket

I have this procedure:

```
(define count-calls
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda char  
           (cond ((null? char) 
                  (begin(set! count (+ 1 count))
                        count))
                 ((eq? char 'how-many-calls) count)
                 ((eq? char 'reset) (set! count 0))))))
```

It does add 1 when (count-calls) is called but when I call (count-calls 'how-many-calls) it doesn't work as intended. I found that if you define (lambda (char) instead of (lambda char the (eq? ...) part is found but for (lambda char) it doesn't seem to recognize char.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont have parentheses around the lambda parameters then you get all the arguments in a list. So your code is comparing 'how-many-calls to a list.

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.3.5 [3m].
Language: racket [custom]; memory limit: 8192 MB.
> ((lambda args (displayln args)) "a")
(a)
> ((lambda args (displayln args)) "a" "b")
(a b)
> ((lambda (args) (displayln args)) "a")
a
> ((lambda (args) (displayln args)) "a" "b")
#<procedure>: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   "a"
   "b"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of coding errors, this should fix them:

```
(define count-calls
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda char
      (cond ((null? char) 
             (set! count (+ 1 count))
             count)
            ((eq? (car char) 'how-many-calls)
             count)
            ((eq? (car char) 'reset)
             (set! count 0))))))
```

In particular, notice that:

- If a `lambda`'s parameters are *not* surrounded by parenthesis (as is the case with `char`), then the procedure expects a *list* of arguments with variable size, possibly empty
- With that in mind, it's clear why you need to do `(car char)` for extracting a parameter, if it was provided
- It's not necessary to use a `begin` after a condition in `cond`, it's implicit

Use the procedure like this:

```
(count-calls)
=> 1
(count-calls 'how-many-calls)
=> 1
(count-calls 'reset)
=> 
(count-calls 'how-many-calls)
=> 0
```

Comment: Many thanks.
I thought about trying (car char) as I saw char was a list in my implementation.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson you're welcome! please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

Extending stchang's answer, here's one way to solve this:

```
(define count-calls
  (let ((count 0))
    (case-lambda
      (() (set! count (+ 1 count)) count)
      ((char) (cond
                ((eq? char 'how-many-calls) count)
                ((eq? char 'reset ) (set! count 0) 'reset)
                (else 'wot?))))))
```